# How to setup Rewrite rule in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

How can I setup a rewrite rule in WordPress with the following URL `"https://mywebsite.com/product-detail/model=MH-TOOL-152&isToolId=1"` This is the redirected link after scanning a QR Code. I should get the parameter `model` value because this is the basis of the product SKU and will place my shortcode under the product-detail page.

I've tried this one below, which redirected me to the home page. I'm trying to setup that it will just display it on the product detail page.

```
function mywebsite_rewrite_rule() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^product-detail/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/model=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'mywebsite_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured out how to use the rewrite rule in WP. This is what I've been working on.

```
// to get the model variable
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_model_var_prodDetail', 10, 1);
function add_model_var_prodDetail($vars_sku){
    $vars_sku[] = 'model';
    return $vars_sku;
}

//rewrite the URL on the specific page product-detail
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_productDetail', 10, 0);
function rewrite_rule_productDetail() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^product-detail/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=page&pagename=product-detail&model=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag( '%model%', '(.+)' );
}
```

Then retrieve the model using `get_query_var`